# How to use quote_literal to add quotes to my postgres query

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql

```
query = ('''SELECT count(*), sum(cast(details->"version") from "public"."table"  where TIMESTAMP>%(start_date)s and TIMESTAMP<%(end_date)s ''' %{"start_date": s_d, "end_date":d_d})
```

I want the query to be like :

```
where TIMESTAMP>'2017-10-23 00:00:00+00:00' and TIMESTAMP<'2017-11-03 00:00:00+00:00'
```

But I get:

```
 where TIMESTAMP>2017-10-23 00:00:00+00:00 and TIMESTAMP<2017-11-03 00:00:00+00:00

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "00"
LINE 1: ...FROM "public"."table" where TIMESTAMP>2017-10-23 00:00:00+0...
```

If I add single quotes it works.

Comment: Have you tried passing the time stamps as parameters? [Passing Parameters To SQL Queries](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

Comment: `cur.execute('''SELECT count(*), sum(cast(details->"version") from "public"."table"  where TIMESTAMP>%s and TIMESTAMP<%s ''', (s_d, d_d))`

Comment: We didn't want to  use this because of SQL injection.

Comment: I'm confused- this way is specifically designed to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I got confused with having single quotes for %s. This works too.

Comment: Great info here: http://bobby-tables.com/python

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, this approach works and prevents SQL-Injection:

```
cur.execute('''
    SELECT count(*),
           sum(cast(details->"version")
      FROM "public"."table"
     WHERE TIMESTAMP>%s AND TIMESTAMP<%s''',
    (s_d, d_d)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try dollar quoting?

```
query = ('''SELECT count(*), sum(cast(details->"version") from "public"."table"  where TIMESTAMP>$$%(start_date)s$$ and TIMESTAMP<$$%(end_date)s$$ ''' %{"start_date": s_d, "end_date":d_d})
```

Comment: This actually worked thank you so much. Before $$ solution I used named places holders(https://pyformat.info)